# ERROR: Invalid argument: ./wait-for-it.sh

Tags: docker, flyway

I have following docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my_sql_conatainer_name:
    image: percona:latest
    container_name: my_sql_conatainer_name
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: secret
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
  migration:
    image: boxfuse/flyway:latest
    container_name: flyway_migration
    volumes:
       - ./flyway_scripts/src/main/resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "migrate", "-url=jdbc:mysql://my_sql_conatainer_name:3306/secret?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false", "-user=root", "-password=password"]
```

`wait-for-it.sh` file locates near the compose file

When I `up` I see following error:

flyway_migration  | ERROR: Invalid argument: ./wait-for-it.sh

What do I wrong?

Comment: What image is the `migration:` container running?  It seems like that line is missing from the `docker-compose.yml`.  The first argument to `wait-for-it.sh` looks wrong too, but that wouldn't cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: @David Maze updated the topic

Comment: @David Maze, what wrong with first argument?

Comment: It'd be expecting the host:port of the database server, which should be `my_sql_percona:3306`.

Comment: There's no `boxfuse/flyway` image on Docker Hub.  Is this a custom-built image and do you have the Dockerfile for it?  (I want to know (a) is there an ENTRYPOINT that will mess up the command line, and (b) does the image actually have the `wait-for-it.sh` script in it?)

Comment: @David Maze, https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker

Comment: @David Maze I don't have anythin additional for migration

Answer (score 5):

The [Dockerfile for that image says:](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L12)

```
ENTRYPOINT ["flyway"]
CMD ["-?"]
```

These two parts are concatenated together, and anything you type as parameters to `docker run` only replaces the `CMD` part.  That is, in effect you're running `flyway ./wait-for-it.sh ...`, and the `flyway` command doesn't understand what to do with it.

If you want to continue on this path, probably your easiest next step is to write your own custom image `FROM boxfuse/flyway` that `COPY wait-for-it.sh` into the image, then adds its own entrypoint script that does the `wait-for-it` step and ends with `exec flyway "$@"`.

Comment: I vam novice in docker. Can you provide all details?